# ubuntu 15.10 installation UEFI problem

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 15.10, secure-boot

I have an ASUS n550-jk laptop and I wanted to install Ubuntu 15.10 alongside Windows 10 (with dual boot) with UEFI. After going to booting menu and choosing boot option (I tried both bootable USB and bootable DVD), Ubuntu freezes after couple of minutes or seconds on the first page(ubuntu name with orange dots and purple background) and this thing happened in both situations(try ubuntu live or install it directly)

I also disabled fast startup , but I can't disable secure boot , because in bios menu there is no option for disabling secure boot , I also upgraded my BIOS but still there is no option for disabling it.

P.S : I also tried 14.04.4 LTS version but I had the same problem.

Comment: Did you try the "nomodeset" needed for Nvidia hardware?  If you type Esc when the purple screen is frozen, do you get a text screen with errors?

Comment: Secure Boot is not your issue -- if it were, you wouldn't be getting as far as the Ubuntu splash screen. I recommend that, when you see the GRUB boot menu, you highlight the option you want to use, then hit `e`. This will enable you to edit the kernel options. Locate the line that includes the string `quiet splash` and remove those two words from the line. This will produce a more verbose boot. When the system hangs, take a screen shot with a digital camera and post the results. Be sure it's in focus and in high enough resolution to read it all.

Comment: @ubfan1 thank you so much , it worked , and after that i upgraded my driver and now its fine .

Answer (score 0):

Try the "nomodeset" needed for Nvidia hardware. If you type Esc when the purple screen is frozen, do you get a text screen with errors?  Add the word in place of the "quiet splash" on the kernel boot line -- type "e" on the grub screen to edit the line, editing/booting instructions at bottom of screen.